# git cloning. What am I doing wrong

Tags: git, github

It has been a little time since I did my last cloning from a repository. My situation is the following:

There is a repository in github that I want to clone into my local system. 
I go to the github page and there are two options for cloning: download as a zip file or open with github desktop. Let's put the github desktop aside for a while.

Now, there is another option for cloning. I go to my terminal and do `git clone <address of the repository>`

In both cases I do get a copy of the repository on my local system successfully *but* it is not a git repository (Of course I can do `git init` to make it one but I am not sure it is the correct procedure-therefore this question)

Of course there is no origin that link this local copy to the github repository. 
My goal is to have a local copy that I can pull frequently so that I can always have an actualized version of.

So my question is what is the correct procedure to clone a github repository to my local system so that I can be linked to it and can frequently pull to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "Download ZIP" option *does not* download a clone, instead it only downloads the latest commit without any history (i.e. there is no `.git` directory inside of it).

> what is the correct procedure to clone a github repository to my local system so that I can be linked to it and can frequently pull to?

Use your terminal and run `git clone <address>` - it *will* be a git repository and it *will* have GitHub set up as a remote (as `origin`). Don't forget to `cd` into the clone directory after it's created in order for the `git` command-line to work on that repo.

It's likely you can't see the `.git` directory because you have "Show hidden (dot-prefixed) files" disabled - you'll see it if you run `ls -al` to show all files.

You will see the remotes by running `git remote -v` - but only if you `cd` into the newly created repo directory.

Comment: Thank you! I was just forgetting to cd into the clone directory!